# How to work with a python collections.deque of custom class instances?

Tags: python-3.x, deque

I am trying to utilize python deque from collections module where the element inside the deque is a custom class instances. I want to know how I can erase/delete an object? Can I use the builtin methods like deque.remove(element) if yes, how? How would it find my custom object?

```
class Buffer(object):

    """ """
    def __init__(self, name, size_total, size_in_cache):
        self.name = name
        self.size_total = size_total

 class Storage(object):
    """
    """
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.CAPACITY = capacity
        self.contents = collections.deque()
        self.capacity_used = 0      

    def push_to_contents(self, buffer_name, buffer_size):
        buf = Buffer(buffer_name, buffer_size)
        self.contents.appendleft(buf)

    def delete_from_contents(self, buffer_name)
        """ HOW??
        How can I use self.contents.remove() here>      
        """
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `collections.deque.remove` operates is by comparing the argument to each item in the deque.  If it finds something which is equal to the argument, it removes it.  Otherwise, it raises a `ValueError`.

Since a `Buffer` object, as you've implemented it, doesn't know how to compare itself with other objects, Python defaults (using the `object` parent class) to comparing the `id` values.

However, if you were to implement the `__eq__` method for your class, you could accomplish what you're looking for.

E.g.,

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Buffer):
        return self.name == other.name and self.size_total == other.size_total
    elif isinstance(other, str):
        return self.name == other
    else:
        return NotImplemented
```

EDIT:

This is all fine and good if you're using Python 3.  In Python 2, you have to implement `__ne__` ("not equal") as well.  It can be as simple as

```
def __ne__(self, other):
    return not self == other
```

Python 3 takes care of this for you automatically.